# Vectorial PDF with xCode using Affinity Designer

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, vector, icons

I'm newbie to Affinity Designer and I'm trying to export some Affinity Designer's project to xCode as vectorial pictures in PDF format.
Initially everything was working fine but, after some attempts (I'm designing the launch screen so, after every export, I make some little adjustments then I re-export the PDF) xCode started giving troubles: sometimes picture doesn't appear in XIB, sometimes appear only some giant pixels and, in very luck times picture appears but very grainy.

I tried changing the pixel's size of the picture (is the only setting I see) but it doesn't change nothing so my questions are:
- what are the requirements for xCode's vectorial PDF (resolution or other settings)?
- is there a precise iter to follow in Affinity Designer to export vectorial and import them in xCode? (I can't find any tutorial about it)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** This issue has been fixed some time ago.

---

I think there's something missing (or wrong... for this context at least) in Affinity Designer's exported PDF files. If you open them in Preview, rotate (and back), then re-save, the vectors will load properly in your app.